MockMvc expected 200 actual 400 - @Valid annotation not respected
We recently upgraded our application to Spring 6, java JDK21 and are now using the jakarta.validation-api. Furthermore, we have a custom class which extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. When we spin up our application in order to test a bad request we do indeed invoke the handleMethodArgumentNotValid() method so there is no issue outside of the test class. We are testing this method override by using a standalone mockMvc implementation within the test class. When we perform a request against the controller the @Valid should be invoked realizing that the @RequestBody has missing arguments yet the controller still returns 200.
What has changed between spring 5 and spring 6 that we cannot utilize the MockMvc standalone to invoke @Valid in a test class? Has anyone encountered this?
We tried throwing the MethodArgumentNotValidException when the service class in the FakeController is invoked, but this will bubble up to a 500 error. This makes sense. Something must have changed between spring 5 and 6. We did see there is a boolean value in the HandlerMethod called validateArguments yet we are unable to set that true within our test class.
Below is the test class and relevant dependency versions
package com.mock.controller;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class ExceptionHandlerTest {

    @Mock private MockService service;
    
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private MockMvc mvc;
    private MockController controller;
    
    private ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver createExceptionResolver(boolean is500Disabled) {
        ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver() {
            @Override
            protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod, Exception exception) {
                Method method = new ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver(CustomGlobalExceptionHandler.class).resolveMethod(exception);
                CustomGlobalExceptionHandler handler = new CustomGlobalExceptionHandler();
                handler.setDisable500(is500Disabled);
                return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(handler, method);
            }
        };
        exceptionResolver.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        exceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
        return exceptionResolver;
    }
    

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        controller = new MockController(service);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(createExceptionResolver(false))
                .build();
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void thatMethodArgumentNotValidExceptionHappens() throws Exception {        
        Request req = new Request(null, "brand", "model", "color", "qty");

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(post("/api/some/post").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(mapper.writeValueAsString(req)))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andReturn();
        
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus());
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(UnescapeResponseJSON(result));
        assertEquals("Error Processing Input", obj.get("detail"));
        assertEquals("id cannot be empty or blank", ((JSONArray)obj.get("errors")).get(0));
        assertEquals("Error Processing Input "+((JSONArray)obj.get("errors")).get(0), obj.get("message"));
    }
    
    private String UnescapeResponseJSON(MvcResult result) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String unescapedJSON  = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
        return unescapedJSON.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
    }

@RestController
public class MockController {
    private MockService service;
    public MockController(MockService service) {this.service = service;}

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/some/post", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> post(@Valid @RequestBody Request req,  BindingResult bindingResult) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.get(10), HttpStatus.OK);
    }        
}

public class MockService {
    public Object get(int i) {
        return new Object();
    }
}

public class Request {
    
    @NotNull(message = "id cannot be empty or blank")
    private String id;
    @NotNull(message = "brand cannot be empty or blank")
    private String brand;
    @NotNull(message = "model cannot be empty or blank")
    private String model;
    @NotNull(message = "color cannot be empty or blank")
    private String color;
    @NotNull(message = "qty cannot be empty or blank")
    private String qty;
    
    public Request() {}
    public Request(String id, String brand, String model, String color, String qty) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.qty = qty;
    }
    
    //omitted getters and setters
}

<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0-M2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.5</version>
</dependency>


Generally this comes from trying to outsmart the dependency management from Spring. In your question there is too little information to be helpful. Please add code, dependencies and the test.

Updated the question with the test class and relevant dependencies. I have seen some post stating you can't perform a validation test using the standalone mock mvc implementation yet we are able to do this in version 5. I can't find any release notes stating otherwise.

For starters use a final and supported version of the Jakarta Validation API (somethinhg like 3.0) next make sure that you also have HIbernate Validator (or whatever implementation you want to use) on the classpath. Without an implementation nothing is going to happen.

Thank you, I've tried all supported and final 3.0 Jakarta Validation API versions and still no luck. Like you said I also verified we have Hibernate Validator within our pom and in the class path by checking I have the jar navigating to eclipse > build path > configure build path > libraries > maven dependencies still no luck. I tried with 8.0.1.Final and 7.0.0.Final. Are you able to reproduce with the provided test class? Originally I thought there may be an issue in the spring web HandlerMethod class where validateArguments was set to false. That boolean has no bearing on validation it seems

There should be nothing preventing you from doing the validation if you have the right dependencies. I'm not going to try your test class as there is no full runnable sample here.

I had the same issue when performing a Spring 5 -> 6 upgrade.
The fix was to ensure the relevant runtime dependency was in place for the expression factory as well as hibernate itself.
e.g. Gradle
testRuntimeOnly("org.glassfish:jakarta.el:4.0.2")

or Maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

